# How to calculate Unbound Values in GridView or Template Column

Tags: silverlight, algorithm, c#-4.0, mvvm-light, radgridview

what i am trying to achive is as follows:

[image]

in the image above you can see a DataGrid bound to sample ObservableItemsCollection ocSOI;

`Code , Description, Total, Delivered` columns are bound to `ocSOI.Code, ocSOI.Description, ocSOI.TotalQty, ocSOI.DeliveredQty` respectively.

`I am trying to Achieve :` When user enters a value in `'This Delivery'` textbox, i want to recalculate the value of column `'Remaining Qty'` and before `SubmitChanges()` of `DomainContext`, i want to change the values of `'ocSOI.DeliveredQty'` adding current delivery in the value `ocSOI.DeliveredQty = ocSOI.DeliveredQty + ThisDelivery`.

I m so stuck at algorithm and i m so lost in the concept as how to achive this thingi. i m really pulling my head out, is it the design flaw that i cannot get my head around it ..... donno ... so lost.... pls help.!!!

p.s. the `SalesOrderItem` entity contains, `ID, Code, Description, TotalQty, DeliveredQty` properties.

p.s.s. I am using MVVM-Light in my viewmodel

Comment: Where is `ThisDelivery` and `Remaining` stored in your ViewModel?

Comment: @Rachel - currently this is the part of question, dont know how to add these values and where to fit them in view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make the `SalesOrderItem` include `ThisDelivery` and `Remaining` properties

Each record should represent an item the customer can order, so should contain all the information needed for that.

You can either make the data item contain individual properties for each column in your Grid

```
public class SalesOrderItem
{
    /* Not writing out full Property Change for sake of simplicity */
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Delivered { get; set; }
    public int ThisDelivery { get; set; }
    public int Remaining { get; set; }

    // When ThisDelivery changes, adjust Remaining value
}
```

or you can lump your item properties under a single object, and just include a property for the item in your `SalesOrderItem`

```
public class SalesOrderItem
{
    /* Not writing out full Property Change for sake of simplicity */
    public ItemModel Item { get; set; }
    public int Delivered { get; set; }
    public int ThisDelivery { get; set; }
    public int Remaining { get; set; }

    // When ThisDelivery changes, adjust Remaining value
}
```

Comment: yeah, the first option, i guessed that one out but wanted to avoid having two more properties there. but i guess this is the simplest and quickest way.... thanks for the answer i would go with option one.